# Thunderbird dashboard style add-on

Tags: email, thunderbird

I was wondering if anyone knew an extension for Mozilla Thunderbirds which gives you a dashboard and sums up what's going on.

- New Messages for each account
- lightning tasks/events for the day

Looking for something like a homescreen/dashboard which could provide alot of the important information in one place.

Comment: +1 thats a great idea, but i doubt anything like that exists

Comment: yea, i have had a good search and can't find anything.